# Setup EnyimMemcached to work with Couchbase Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, couchbase, enyim

I'm trying, without luck at all, to make the [EnyimMemcached](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached) library work with [Couchbase Community server](http://www.couchbase.com/download) that I have installed on my local machine.

I'm using in `web.config`

```xml
  <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
  </sectionGroup>
```

```xml
  <enyim.com>
    <memcached protocol="Binary">
      <servers>
        <add address="localhost" port="8091" />
      </servers>
      <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" connectionTimeout="00:00:10" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
      <authentication type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.PlainTextAuthenticator, Enyim.Caching" userName="Administrator" password="1234" />
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
```

but I keep getting no hits on the local server and the

```cs
var result = _client.Store(StoreMode.Add, key, val);
```

keeps returning `false`.

> Is there any change that any of you work with it and can **show me some light on setting it up correctly?**

Comment: Are you using the CouchbaseClient? - http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/current.

Comment: no, I wanted to use `Enyim.Caching.Memcached` instead as that's what I have in the cloud, and I wanted to still work on my local machine, but the current Memcached server does not allowed connections outside Amazon EC2 domain.

Comment: CouchbaseClient is a subclass of MemcachedClient in Enyim.Caching, so the Couchbase client layer really just takes care of the Couchbase specific setup.  All of your caching calls would actually be performed through the Enyim code...

Comment: I use memcache from couchbase server 2.0 through Enyim.Caching, but I run my memcache bucket on separate port (without password authentication). I can provide my config later if you need.

Comment: @Alex would be nice if you could share your configuration...

Comment: Try something like:
 <enyim.com>
    <memcached>
      <servers>
        <add address="localhost" port="10001" />
      </servers>
      <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" connectionTimeout="00:00:10" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
In the morning (now 0:30) I'll connect to my server and provide my config.

Answer (score 1):

My config:

```
<sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
</sectionGroup>
 ...
<enyim.com>
  <memcached>
    <servers>
      <add address="127.0.0.1" port="10001" />
    </servers>
    <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" connectionTimeout="00:10:00" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
  </memcached>
</enyim.com>
```

Basic wrapper for System.Web.Caching.Cache

```
public class MemcachedCache : ICache
{
        private MemcachedClient cache;

        private TimeSpan _timeSpan = new TimeSpan(
            Settings.Default.DefaultCacheDuration_Days,
            Settings.Default.DefaultCacheDuration_Hours,
            Settings.Default.DefaultCacheDuration_Minutes, 0);

        public MemcachedCache()
        {
            cache = new MemcachedClient();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a cache object based on the cache_key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cache_key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object Get(string cache_key)
        {
            return cache.Get(cache_key);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Override to allow expiration at a specific date/time and a priority level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cache_key"></param>
        /// <param name="cache_object"></param>
        /// <param name="expiration"></param>
        /// <param name="priority"></param>
        public void Set(string cache_key, object cache_object, DateTime expiration, CacheItemPriority priority)
        {
            cache.Store(StoreMode.Set, cache_key, cache_object, expiration);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override to cache for a specified amount of time and a priority level.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cache_key"></param>
        /// <param name="cache_object"></param>
        /// <param name="expiration"></param>
        /// <param name="priority"></param>
        public void Set(string cache_key, object cache_object, TimeSpan expiration, CacheItemPriority priority)
        {
            cache.Store(StoreMode.Set, cache_key, cache_object, expiration);
        }
}
```

For your configuration also check if all ports opened (8091, 8092). If you use separate port configuration also check if it is opened.